# How is a file 'read'?

Tags: c, file, memory

When we open a file, in any programming language (if you can reference **C** much better) how exactly is the file's that data retrieved for the program's use? Is the text/image loaded into memory as bytes like everything else then retrieved by grabbing the values in memory?

**Please, no mythical explanation** telling me the file is just "there" but instead, refer to how the file is "opened".

Comment: See [Intro to File Input/Output in C](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/)

Comment: If you really want to know all those details, then take a class about how operating system is implemented.

Comment: @Lee Duhem I asked for an answer not a suggestion, but thank you.

Comment: Your question is very broad... "like everything else" - can you give na example of what "everything" you consider known. What level of reading files are you interested in - physical (disk, IO ports, network), OS IO, language/framework run-time, user's parsing code)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov From the 'broadness' of my question you may notice I have no idea how those things work so why ask about more complicated issues? I am not asking about a specific implementation full of details I won't understand, I simply asked how a file is 'opened' or loaded into memory if it is at all really by the operative system as perreal mentioned. He seemed to understand my question.

Comment: @polymorph Well, a fully answer to your question will be very, very long (a book, maybe), much longer than you may be expected. So please do not say you want to know every details, it is (almost) never a good idea.

Comment: @LeeDuhem If you take a look at perreal's answer he provided me with actual information, are you here to argue instead?

Comment: @polymorph No, of course not. Just to point out your question is too board. How to make it more specific? What about a naive implementation of `cp` by using standard C or system calls only, both could help you understand how to open, read, then write files. Is this what you want?

Comment: @LeeDuhem in simple terms can you explain, in general, how the operative system reads a file from the hard-drive and make it available for C code, for example to be able to grab what is written inside. Again, very broadly for a newbie.

Comment: @polymorph Well, my explanation will include some of kernel will find that according to this, and it will copy that to memory, and so on, and you are going to ask more Hows, and I will say "read a book" or "take a class" evently, so let us jump to that directly, I do not think I could offer you a satisfactory explanation about how file read/write is implemented in operating system kernel. Beside that, as a user (a.k.a. programmer) of operating system API (a.k.a. system calls) or standard libraries of programming languages, you generally does not need to concern how them get implemented.

Comment: Well, typically, the open() call generates an interrupt to kernel state.  The block-device driver raises an fd struct to manage the buffering, The fd and filepath parameters are loaded into an interrupt-request block, the IRB is queued to the top level of the addressed disk driver, the calling thread is blocked on a semaphore in the IRB, the block device driver signals a smeaphore to make the disk driver dequeue the IRB and process it, the driver uses interrupts and/or DMA to communicate with the bus controller for the drive requested, the disk controller on the device prioritises its outstand

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages use operating system facilities to handle files. What you really want to know is how this is done in the operating system.

Generally, a structure in the memory is initialized which keeps track of the read/write position.

In the OS or some library, there is a buffer associated with each file and the actual data is moved to this buffer. The buffer is small though, not the whole file.

see also: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-8.html

Comment: so the buffer is replaced with more information when reading from it reached the end?

Comment: yes, you don't read/write a small part of the file, it's always a larger fixed size chunk when that part is not already in the buffer.